# Calendar scroll to current month in date range picker

Tags: jquery

I am using t-datepicker https://t-datepicker.getqwerty.com/documents.html in my company 's project  please open this url ( http://webhungers.com/globb/globb_fixes_v1/)   in mobile and click on depart . Issue is that on selecting any date for example 8 april 2023 calendar is going to current month . Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). See also [ask] and the [tour], and how to create a [mre] of your issue, and try again. Thanks.

Comment: I am not understand your query

Comment: Well, did you read the contents of all those links?